# laravel access DB facade in config files

Tags: laravel, config

I would like to make a DB query within my config/session.php
Unfortunately it seems that the framework is not fully loaded when this file gets evaluated and I get

```
class DB does not exist
```

I have tried DB:: and app()->make('db'):

```
'lifetime' => (function() {
    $url = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] : '';
    $url = str_replace('www.', '', $url);
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $host = isset($parts['host']) ? $parts['host'] : $parts['path'];

    $campaign = app()->make('db')->table('campaigns')->where('url', $host)
        ->orWhere('url', 'like', $host.'%')
        ->orWhere('url', 'like', '%'.$host.'%')->first();

    if($campaign && $campaign->session_lifetime)
        return $campaign->session_liftetime;
    else
        return 24 * 60;
})(),
```

Comment: try with `\DB::('table_name')` to access an existing DB table

Comment: @lewis4u still the same: Class 'DB' not found

Comment: Are you using lumen or laravel??

Comment: @lewis4u laravel

Comment: I assume you already have `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` beneath the namespace Chris (for using DB::)?

Comment: @Option yes, I have tried that also. This gives me: A facade root has not been set.

Comment: wait, why did you need to run db on config? i believe config runs **before** the db config loaded. so you out of luck. better to develop your own 'config' rather than misuse the current config.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use Facades while config files are loading.